# How can I use JSON data past to a web server in Python

Tags: python, json, http

My web server is something like that with BaseHTTPServer :

```
def do_POST(self):
    if None != re.search('/connect/*', self.path):
        ctype, pdict = cgi.parse_header(self.headers.getheader('content-type'))
    if ctype == 'application/json':
        length = int(self.headers.getheader('content-length'))
        data = cgi.parse_qs(self.rfile.read(length), keep_blank_values=1)
        recordID = self.path.split('/')[-1]                                                                                                                        
        LocalData.records[recordID] = data
        print data                                                                                                           
    else:
        data = {}
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
```

How can I stock JSON information received to a Python structure and Python struture to JSON please ? I see how I can use HTTP, for example the header, but not how to use JSON stock inside. I need help. Thank you.

Cordially

Arnaud

Answer (score 1):

To get a python object from your CGI data:

> import json
>
> obj = json.loads(data)

To go the other way:

> json_str = json.dump(obj)